# Another Riesz-ian Question Regarding Chapter 2 of Rudin's Real and Complex

Tags: analysis

So as to save space/time, the proof is detailed here: http://data.imf.au.dk/kurser/advanalyse/F06/lecture16-print.pdf

My question is why is it that the measure of compact $K$ (in page 17 of source, third paragraph) is necessarily greater that the functional's value on $f$ ie: $\mu(K)\geq\Lambda(f)$ ?

thank you,

Answer (score 1):

For any open set $V\subseteq X$,

$$\mu(V):=\sup\{\Lambda(f): f\prec V\},$$

and for any subset $E\subseteq X$,

$$\mu(E):=\inf\{\mu(V): E\subseteq V\}.$$

Let $K$ be a compact set, with $K\subset V$, where $V$ is open. You want to show $\mu(K)\geq \Omega(f)$.

Well, it's a definition chase:

$$\mu(K):=\inf_V\{\sup_f\{\Lambda(f): f\prec V\}\}\geq \inf_V \{\Lambda(f)\}=\Lambda(f)$$

Really we're just using the fact that if $a_n\geq c$ then $\inf_n a_n \geq c$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand what you are saying. I will summarize the proof:

For open $V$ there is a real $\alpha$: $ \alpha< \mu(V)$ and there exists a $f$ dominated by V : $\alpha \leq \Lambda(f)$. One can consider an open set $W$ containing the support $K$ of $f$, from which it follows that $\mu(W) \geq \Lambda(f) $ now taking the inf over all such W we have $\mu(K)=\inf(\mu(W): K\subset W, \text{f dom by W})\geq \Lambda(f)$. Whereby the conclusion follows.